# Opencv read image data from hbase

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, hbase

Image data stored in hbase and retrieved as byte array using below code.

`byte[] image_data = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Data"), Bytes.toBytes("data"));`

I need to convert into Opencv Mat for processing. While using below code I got invalid image.

`Mat mat = new Mat();
 mat.put(0, 0, image_data);`

Tried How to convert an byte array to Opencv Mat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image decode in Opencv for creating Mat from byte array

`Mat mat = Highgui.imdecode(new MatOfByte(image_data), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);`